# oracle sql count(*) with rows not matched

Tags: sql, database, oracle, datetime, outer-join

I have a oracle query:

```
select to_char(te.HORA, 'hh24:mi') HORARIO, count(1) CANTIDAD 
from db.t_error te
where (te.error LIKE 'ERR-108' or te.error LIKE 'ERR-256')
and te.HORA >= to_HORA('29-07-2016 18:50', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi')
and te.HORA <= to_HORA('29-07-2016 19:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi')
group by to_char(te.HORA, 'hh24:mi')
order by to_char(te.HORA, 'hh24:mi');
```

Result (Table):

```
HORARIO | CANTIDAD
18:53            2
18:56            2
18:58            1
18:59            1
```

but I need Results to include all minutes (table):

```
HORARIO | CANTIDAD
18:50            0
18:51            0
18:52            0
18:53            2
18:54            0
18:55            0
18:56            2
18:57            0
18:58            1
18:59            1
19:00            0
```

Count minute to minute with 0 values or not matched result for count(1).

I hope help!

Thanks.

Comment: You probably also want `te.error LIKE 'ERR-108%' or te.error LIKE 'ERR-256%')` to count rows where error starts with `ERR-108` etc. followed by zero or more characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good solution (it should be implemented to work directly with your code, not as an add-on), but it illustrates how this should be done.

`to_date` in this context adds the time (using the `hh24:mi` format model) to the first day of the current month, but you don't care about that since you extract the hour and minute and discard the rest anyway.

Biggest thing to fix in your code is that you work with strings. Best to put everything in date datatype, group by date datatype (to the minute), and only use `to_char()` for display purposes at the very end. Please write back if you need help with that.

```
with
     your_table ( horario, cantidad ) as (
       select '18:53', 2 from dual union all
       select '18:56', 2 from dual union all
       select '18:58', 1 from dual union all
       select '18:59', 1 from dual
     ),
     all_times ( horario ) as (
       select to_char( to_date('18:50', 'hh24:mi') + (level - 1) / (24 * 60), 'hh24:mi')
       from   dual
       connect by level <= 1 + (to_date('19:00', 'hh24:mi') - 
                                                 to_date('18:50', 'hh24:mi')) * 24 * 60
     )
select a.horario, nvl(y.cantidad, 0) as cantidad
from   all_times a left outer join your_table y
                   on a.horario = y.horario
order by horario
;

HORARIO   CANTIDAD
------- ----------
18:50            0
18:51            0
18:52            0
18:53            2
18:54            0
18:55            0
18:56            2
18:57            0
18:58            1
18:59            1
19:00            0

11 rows selected.
```

**Edited**:

For a "cheap" solution with no extra effort, you can plug your original query directly into the "your_table" factored subquery, like so (but I don't have your base tables, so I can't test).

```
with
     your_table ( horario, cantidad ) as (
       select   to_char(te.HORA, 'hh24:mi') HORARIO, count(1) CANTIDAD 
       from     db.t_error te
       where    (te.error LIKE 'ERR-108' or te.error LIKE 'ERR-256')
         and    te.HORA >= to_HORA('29-07-2016 18:50', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi')
         and    te.HORA <= to_HORA('29-07-2016 19:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi')
       group by to_char(te.HORA, 'hh24:mi')        
     ),
     all_times ( horario ) as (
       select to_char( to_date('18:50', 'hh24:mi') + (level - 1) / (24 * 60), 'hh24:mi')
       from   dual
       connect by level <= 1 + (to_date('19:00', 'hh24:mi') - 
                                                 to_date('18:50', 'hh24:mi')) * 24 * 60
     )
select a.horario, nvl(y.cantidad, 0) as cantidad
from   all_times a left outer join your_table y
                   on a.horario = y.horario
order by horario
;
```

Comment: i replace your_table with my real table name

Comment: Err - no, my code EXACTLY AS WRITTEN is not missing keyword, the proof is that it ran perfectly fine and it produced the output I showed. You can't replace "your_table" with your real table name, because "your_table" is a name for the RESULT of your query, not for your original table.

Comment: And the code must count the errors: ERR-108 and ERR-256 in exact minute...

Comment: If you want a "cheap" solution with no extra effort, in my code in the definition of "your_table" delete the hardcoded rows and instead copy and paste your QUERY (not the name of your table).

Comment: I will add it to my post - give me a minute.

Comment: Nice way to generate a range of hours/minutes.  My attempt that I didn't post worked but wasn't self-documenting like yours.